# Search a spoken term within media files

Tags: media-manager

How would you go for searching a spoken term within a media file?

Let's say for example I want to know whether in a specific movie (or bunch of movies) someone says the words "Hello World". Moreover I want to know the time slice in which the term is spoken and I want to copy it in a different media file, so that the new file contains only the string "Hello World" spoken by the actor from the movie.

I need this to create a database from spoken terms. I could of course use TTS engine to generate .wav file with pronunciation of given term (or text), but the speech will be machine generated and that is not what I want.

Comment: Just to be clear - are you asking for an audio search engine?

Comment: Yes, something like that :)